# Antenna Gain Vs IP68 plastic enclossure

Tags: antenna, gain, 433mhz

I would like to buy this IP68 plastic enclossure below for my electronic project:
https://www.chinaenclosure.com/products/102-70-52mm-ip68-waterproof-plastic-enclosures-for-electronics-from-china-manufacturer-AK10514.html

Inside this enclossure, i plan to put an RF antenna connected with my PCB.

I would like to know if my  antenna gain would not be affected, even when the antenna where be inside this enclossure, and if i will still have a good RF 433mhz signal

Thanks a lot.. ( and sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 0):

ABS (and most plastics without additives that make them conductive) are pretty transparent to RF frequencies in that range.

You can ask the supplier for the resin data sheet, there are only a few resin suppliers in the world and the data is usually pretty good. If they can't supply that they're probably not a real manufacturer but some kind of middleman.